# Submitting a php table with input boxes

Tags: php, sql, post, multidimensional-array, submit

I've really been racking my brain with this. I'll try to explain it to the best of my ability. It is mainly a data entry form.

First, there are three variables to start with. One is an array of regions (NYC, DC, etc) and the other to is a starting date (ex: 01/01/2012) and an ending date (ex: 1/15/2012)

In previous pages, the user selected the number of regions, selected the starting date to start recording, and the ending date. The intent is to enter 'points' and the dates are basically by week.

This is what the form is supposed to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGdBx.png

In the boxes aside from the first column and first row, they are all input boxes. So, each input box is associated with the value at each end of the table (for example, the box next to NYC and under 01/01/2012 would enter data for NYC in the date range from 01/01/2012 to 01/08/2012).

My question is: How do I go about building this? Should I use a big 2d array? How would the submit button know which input boxes correspond to which date/region? My initial thought is maybe a hidden value that's like $array[0][x], $array[x][0], but I'm not sure.

I'm not really good at explaining, so I apologize in advance if anyone can't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Come on people, don't just downvote, provide some feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// hard coding these values for example
// but for OP's case these might be coming from a previous page 
$date_array = Array("01/01/2012", "01/08/2012", "01/15/2012");
$region_array = Array("NYC", "DC");
```

Now generate that form/table in your image like this:

```
<form name="test_form" id="test_form" action="submit_form.php" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
             <td></td>
             <?php
                 foreach ($date_array as $date){
                     echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
                 }
             ?>
         </tr>
         <?php
         foreach ($region_array as $region){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$region."</td>";
            foreach ($date_array as $date){
                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"".$region."_".$date."\"></td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
       ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

now for submit_form.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){
        if ($k != "submit"){
            // split the form input on _
            $input = explode("_", $k);
            echo "<BR>City: " . $input[0];
            echo "<BR>Date: " . $input[1];
            echo "<BR>Value: " . $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure. There might be some small formatting errors here and there but it should work for the most part.

Comment: The $_POST['submit'] wasn't working, it works when I use method="post" in the form definition however. If submit_form.php is a separate page, then I think $_POST was supposed to be $_GET. Anyway, whether it's the same page with POST or the next with GET, it gives me an error. Undefined offset: 1 in C:\(whatever) on line 34. This line contains the code echo "<BR>Date: " . $input[1]; Something weird is going on, this is what it looks like: [link to screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/IuebStg.jpg) It seems $input[1] keeps being empty, I'll look into it before you reply.

Comment: I updated method="POST" part. POST can submit to a page that is not same as the original page. So try the updated code.

Comment: Sorry, my link works now, had a typo in it. This is what it looks like after the correction: http://i.imgur.com/IuebStg.jpg Note: I entered 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in the fields.

Comment: I updated the code just now. changed             $input = explode("_", $v); to             $input = explode("_", $k); in submit_form.php can you try now ?

Comment: Ah, now it looks correct. City: NYC Date: 01/01/2012 Value: 5, then City: NYC Date: 01/08/2012 Value: 6, etc etc. I actually have no knowledge of this explode() function, so it was a bit awkward for me to debug this. I only looked it up just now. Now that you've made that handy loop for me, instead of echos I can use input[0] and input[1] to place the $v in the correct table in the database. Thanks a lot, I've learned a lot. If I screw up sticking them into the database I'll post again, but I think I know enough to figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to say in all this, but I actually need two forms with one submit, one for a certain type of value, let's say value1, and another for value2. or two inputs for each box. I've been trying to modify this to do that but I keep messing up. So for the regions and date ranges, I need to enter value1 and value2, currently it only works for value1.

Comment: I don't think you can do 2 forms with one submit... you can do multiple fields in single forms though... are you sure you really need 2 forms ?

Comment: I mean something like this: http://i.imgur.com/jItUYIG.jpg . I just copied the echo statement in the table and re-pasted it between the <td></td>. I want to make it save two values there.

Comment: you should be able to extend the logic in my answer to do that easily. You want to give that a shot and write some code for that ? You might want to use my answer as a starting point and then if you run into an issue you can post your code for review on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: I got it so that when the echo runs, it runs the first name which i changed to .region."value1_".date. and then runs the second name .region"value2_".date. so I could likely keep track of them by doing a count through the loop and knowing the first one is an even number and the second one is odd, but that seems like I'm ignoring the simpler way of doing it. I'll do that unless you think it's going around the problem rather than solving it, and if you think that's the case I'll post it on codereview. Of course, if it works then it works, no matter how sloppy it's done, maybe. :P

Comment: I posted it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28893/multiple-input-fields-from-php-table Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant on a commonly asked question.

In principle the foreach statement is perhaps the best option.  pseudocode:

Collate all possible date ranges into a single array (array_merge, array_unique, array_sort) to generate your headers

foreach($region as $dates)
       {
       display the button for $date['startdate'] if is in_array of dates;
       display the button for  $date['enddate'] if is in_array of dates;
       repeat...
       }

The big problem you are going to have is dealing with the layout.  The obvious solution (at the risk of ire hereon) is to use an HTML table.  This is simple and automatically adjusts itself.

```
$nextline="<TR>";
if(is in_array($datetotest,$listofdates))
    {
    $nextline.="<TD><CODE FOR BUTTON></TD>";
    }
    else
    {
    $nextline.="<TD><BR></TD>";
    }
```

Your alternative (and probably slicker) solution is to enclose all your buttons in a suitable span or other tag and neatly arrange them using CSS.  This gives you more layout options but can be a bit of a headache with arbitrarily large datasets.

Comment: I haven't been using PHP and HTML very long, so I apologize if my questions seem obvious, but I gotta ask them: In your example, the user presses the button and then enters data? Or is the button supposed to be the input field? Also, the way you have it, if someone inputs a number into the field in the table and hits submit, it will know which region and date it will be associated with?